# How to automap Table-per-class hierarchy in S#arp architecture

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, s#arp-architecture, automapping

I am pretty new to S#harp architecture and fluent nhibernate. I was trying to build a sample solution using the template.
MappingIntegrationTest fails for me when I try to run it for the following domains

```
public class Component
{
  public virtual string comp { get; set; }
}

public class Parent : Entity
{
   public virtual string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Child1: Parent
{
   public virtual Component Blah { get; set }
}
```

The ParentMap looks like following:

```
public class ParentMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Parent>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Parent> mapping)
    {
        mapping.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Type")
            .SubClass<Child1>(m =>
                            {
                               m.Component(c => c.Blah, c =>
                                    {
                                        c.Map(x => x.comp , "comp");
                                    }
                            }
    }
}
```

The mapping integration tests fail for me
  * Database was not configured through Database method.

----> NHibernate.MappingException : An association from the table Parent refers to an unmapped class: Component

Do I need to remove these classes from AutoMapper?